# What is the marker field(PhatomData) used in std::task::Context?

Tags: rust

I'm reading the futures::task::Context source code, I don't understand what the _ maker is for. Although there are comments, I still don't understand what he is talking about.

```
pub struct Context<'a> {
    waker: &'a Waker,
    // Ensure we future-proof against variance changes by forcing
    // the lifetime to be invariant (argument-position lifetimes
    // are contravariant while return-position lifetimes are
    // covariant).
    _marker: PhantomData<fn(&'a ()) -> &'a ()>,
}
```

Can any one help me?Thanks very much !

Comment: Check the documentation for the `PhantomData<T>` https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html it is basically a way to make compiler to do type checks, as if the type (`Context`) actually stored the type `T` referred by the `PhantomData`. The comment is talking about a variance, check here for some details https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html#variance (in particular a table)

Comment: I know what is PhatomData and invariance, but I still don't understand why "_marker: PhantomData<fn(&'a ()) -> &'a ()>," is necessary, I have tried to remove this marker in source code of futures package, no compilation errors is generated.